# Androidplot: Create a square plot area

Tags: android, androidplot

In Androidplot, I need to create a square plot area. i.e. the actual plot area not the graph area. This is so that the scale on both axis are the same i.e. the distance between two grid points on the x-axis is the same as the y-axis. I hope this makes sense.

In Androidplot I can set the graph area size using:

```
    final Size sm = new Size(900, SizeLayoutType.ABSOLUTE, 900, SizeLayoutType.ABSOLUTE);
    myPositionLines.getGraphWidget().setSize(sm);
```

But then how do I ensure that the plot area comes out also 'square'. I have made sure all margins/paddings are set to zero...

Would there be something like this ... myPlot.setPlotSize()...

Please help!

Answer (score 1):

There are several factors involved here.  As you noted, theres a difference between the plot (the actual View element that Android positions) and the graph widget (the area inside of the plot View that visually represents the graph portion of the plot.)

It sounds like you've got the View part covered so I'll focus only on the graph widget piece.  The first thing you need to do is set the size and orientation of the graph widget inside of the plot.  Take a look at the X/Y Positioning Widgets and Sizing Widgets sections of the [Styling Your Plot doc](http://androidplot.com/docs/styling-your-plot/).  You can get a handle to the graph widget by invoking `plot.getGraphWidget()`.

The next step is to decide how to subdivide the graph area for drawing; this is what determines how many lines are visible and how many units each tick along the domain or range axis represents.  You do this by setting boundaries.  For example:

```
plot.setDomainBoundaries(0, 10, BoundaryMode.FIXED);
plot.setRangeBoundaries(0, 0, BoundaryMode.FIXED);
```

This subdivides the graph area into a 10x10 grid.  The `BoundaryMode.FIXED` portion tells Androidplot not to auto-frame the data being plotted, which it tries to do by default.

Comment: Thanks Nick. This does answer the question mostly but when I was referencing the plot area in my question above what I meant was the area of within in the axis of the plot. 

So to be clear, there is the plot area, and within this is the graph area (widget) and within that is the area bound by axis of the plot.

What I am looking for is to have the area within the axis, square. Currently I am adjusting the bottom padding for the graphwidget as this is not the same as the left padding by default.